# Problems running both JUnit tests and Selenium/Cucumber tests at the same time

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I have a basic Maven/Spring test project with some simple JUnit tests and Selenium/Cucumber tests that I later want to run using Github Actions, but first I want to make sure they run locally.

This is the JUnit "test":

```
package com.example.CucumberSelenium;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest
public class GithubActionsTests {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

This is my Cucumber test runner file:

```
package com.example.CucumberSelenium;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/com/example/CucumberSelenium/resources/features", glue = "com.example.CucumberSelenium.stepdefs")
public class CucumberTestRunnerTest {
}
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberSelenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CucumberSelenium</name>
    <description>testing</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/GithubActionsTests.java</include>
                        <include>**/CucumberTestRunnerTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my file structure:
[image]

Both tests run fine by them themselves using IntelliJ. But when running `mvn test` only the cucumber tests are running.

Changing `maven-surefire-plugin` version to 2.22.2 will reverse the result, only JUnit test is running and not the cucumber tests. So I guess there is some dependecy issue or issue with the plugin, but I can't figure out what. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot 3.2 which pulls in JUnit 5. While also using `cucumber-junit` which depends on JUnit 4.

Support for JUnit 5 was introduced into Surefire somewhere around v2.22. But Surefire can not run JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 together at the same time and so defaults to the latest version of JUnit when both are available.

For the short term you can work around this by including the `junit-vintage-engine`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

For the long term it would be better to stop depending on JUnit 4 all together and switch to the [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#cucumber-junit-platform-engine). You can find a working example (without Spring) in the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton.

Comment: Adding `junit-vintage-engine` did it! Thank you  Will look into `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` as well.